# Redshift. drop table under condition

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I have ETL process that loads data into some redshift table (tbl1_tmp).
Now if data is loaded (count > 0) I want to drop another table (tbl1) and rename tmp1_tmp --> tbl1.

Can I write some SQL code that allows me to drop table in certain condition is met? (count > 0 in my case)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that condition? Does it mean that your ETL process sometimes loads empty table and in that case you want not to proceed? 

Anyways - in sql it's not possible to mix DDL statements (`DROP`/`CREATE TABLE`) and queries (`SELECT`). Where do you run your queries from? If it's a bash or python script then you can have the condition there.

Comment: @botchniaque empty table is just example condition. I have ETL that can sometimes go wrong and I dont want to actually use corrupted data in this case.
I'm running ETL in AWS data pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift basically runs SQL. It is not an ETL tool itself.

You would need to write some code that to check the contents of a table and then, if desired, issue a `DROP TABLE` command. There is no ability to "drop table in certain conditions".